# Saving Date in IndexedDB store an empty object

Tags: javascript, date, indexeddb

I'm trying to save some objects in IndexDB. One of the properties of this object is a Date Javascript object.
This Date property is always save as an Empty Object at IndexDB.

```
var trans = db.transaction(["todo"], "readwrite");
            var store = trans.objectStore("todo");
            lastIndex++;
            var myDateObject = new Date();
            var request = store.put({
                    "id": lastIndex,
                    "text": todoText, 
                    "date": myDateObject
            });
```

But what I obtain is:

```
{Key: 1, 
 Value { 
         Id: 1, 
         text: "myText",
         date:{}           // ??
        }
 }
```

Due to the documentation is possible to do it:

> value Each record has a value, which could include anything that can
>   be expressed in JavaScript, including boolean, number, string, date,
>   object, array, regexp, undefined, and null.

As can be read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB#key

Plunker to reproduce: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/bcH3mmDC3dQ8S89J4dNl?p=preview

Disclaimer: I've recycle a Plunker made by Jayesh Chandrapal from http://embed.plnkr.co/ip6owK/preview.

Comment: Hi Mario here is a simple indexed db todo solution https://github.com/denispasovski/IndexedDbToDo

Comment: Thanks Deni, in that example the Date is being stored as Timespan and as String, but I'm trying to store a Date object as the documentation propose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in Chrome Developer Tools, that is not showing properly the data, but the data is in the IndexedDB.

Using the same plunker, I've added a new cell to bind the date, and it's showing it.

```
<td>{{todo.date}}</td>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wVDgGFwhgOMJtelgZsEi?p=preview

I've open a Chromium issue:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=399224

Comment: MAybe you can also help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546716/sort-by-number-date ! Sorting by date would be alos i option but i thought like this maybe its easier!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to serialise your date object before saving in db

Comment: Dates don't need to be serialized as the documentation said.