# Unexpected behavior sorting by number/date in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

For my databse i've created an index called `time` on `created_at`:

```
var os = thisDB.createObjectStore(name, { keyPath :  "id" });
os.createIndex("time", "created_at", {unique: false });
```

As you can see i save the time as a unix integer:

```
entry['created_at'] = Date.new(entry['created_at']).unix();
var request = sto.add(entry);
```

So that at end in the console the data looks like this:

[image]

My question is how i can get all data in `asc` or `desc` created at direction:

Because when i go through the data with a cursor:

```
function open_cursor(){
  var objectStore = ENTRYDB.transaction('entries').objectStore('entries').index('time');
  var request = objectStore.openCursor();
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {handle_open(event)};
}
function handle_open(evt){
  var cursor = evt.target.result;
  if (cursor) {
    console.log(cursor.value);
    cursor.continue();
  }
}
```

Its not sorted by the created at time! It is random! THANKS

Comment: It looks correct to me, so I cannot be of much help. When you open the cursor on the index using the default arguments (undefined key range, 'next' direction), the result should be enumerated in ascending order of the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort ascending/descending in the openCursor function by giving it the second parameter: index.openCursor(undefined, "next"); or "prev" for descending.

Sorting should work on the index, also when you do not provide a next or prev (next is default). When you call openCursor on the index, it loops them in the same way chrome-dev-tools shows them when clicking the "time" index in the debugger.

Are you using the shim by any chance (maybe for iOS/android)? (https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim), because it is a known issue sorting doesn't really work there. If you aren't sure then I guess this paragraph doesn't apply to you..

**EDIT** You are problably not using the shim because I see a screenshot of the indexedDb from chrome dev-tools, wich you could not have done when using the shim as it uses a different storage mechanism).